# How can I combine an attribute and nth-of-type in querySelector?

Tags: javascript, selectors-api

I am trying to select a cell in a table by it's attribute (for which I could use querySelector("[data-name]"), but I want it to return the elements in the third column only. Is it possible to combine an attribute search with nth-of-type(2)?

I've tried using querySelector("[data-name]:nth-of-type(2)"] but that doesn't work.

Comment: `querySelector("[data-name]:nth-of-type(2)"] ` you mean `querySelector("[data-name]:nth-of-type(2)")` - and 2 would be the second, not the third

Comment: Why can't you use nth-of-type and on that try conditioning o n data attributes

Comment: 2 is actually the third column, since it starts counting at 0.

Comment: there is no such animal as the 0th of something, so 1 = 1st, 2 = 2nd ... etc ... but I'm sure you know far more than me, considering your querySelector in the question isn't even valid javascript syntax

Comment: You are right, i was thinking about the columns, not the nth-of-type.

Comment: 1st column is column 1, not column 0 ... the cell is index 0, but it's column 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for 3rd column try with nth-of-type(3)

:nth-of-type() is a css selector and index of the first child will be 1

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp

```js
console.log(document.querySelector("table tr [data-name]:nth-of-type(3)"));
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td data-name="1">1</td>
       <td data-name="2">2</td>
        <td data-name="3">3</td>
    <tr>
      </table>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Apparently I had a syntax error apart from the 2 instead of 3 mistake.

Comment: @YamilAbugattas Glad to help :)